# Initializing std::vector of structs

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

I wish to add a bunch of objects of this type to a std::vector.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int handle;
} Handle;
```

Handle is defined within a C API header which I am unable to change.

I'm doing this at the moment but am wondering if it can be done as a one-liner.

```
Handle handle1 = {12};
Handle handle2 = {13};
std::vector<Handle> handles = boost::assign::list_of(handle1)(handle2);
```

I using a C++98 compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a `make_handle` function:

```
Handle make_handle(int handle) {
    Handle ret = { handle };
    return ret;
}
```